Presto SQL-Extract sting from the last occurence of char (:) from the right
My goal is to get all the substrings after the last occurene of the char hypen from the right in each string separated by hypen. Ive tried, but i'm getting wrong values if there are multiple "Hypen" encountered from the string. Is there any workaround or approach. Thank you in Advance.
sample input and result:
my code:
substring(con.itemid,INSTR(con.itemid,'-')+1) as itemid_suffix,

Another code but getting wrong result:
select SUBSTR(ltrim(regexp_extract('AAAA-BBBB-PUB','-([^:]*)',1)),1,2)

Maybe you could also use REGEXP_REPLACE(con.itemid, '.*-', '') possibly you can even omit the replacement part in presto sql?  I'm not sure and can't test it...

Btw. your title says something about char (:) (colon?), further you have [^:]* in your sample which is confusing as it sounds you want to target the last - hyphen. Consider edit...

Based on the provided data you can use simple pattern of any non-hyphen characters and end of the string - [^-]*$:
-- sample data
with dataset(str) as(
    VALUES ('aaa-bbb'),
        ('aaa-bbb-ccc'),
        ('111-112') 
) 

-- query
SELECT regexp_extract(str, '[^-]*$')
FROM dataset;

Output:
 _col0
-------
 bbb
 ccc
 112


Hi @Guru Stron, Thanks for your reply. Just try the code and its working if the string are all Letter. When i try this type of string with number it doesnt work. sample string 100-19977-PUB , the result given was 19977-PUB, it should be PUB.

@Jon tried this - works just fine for me (as expected, pattern does not differentiate between letters and numbers), potentially you have different "hyphen" characters in the strings or something else is going on, please add [mre] (including exact data and query used).
